# Dynamically change the height of an element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: Column A and B]
Well here we have two columns A and B. The thing is column A generally contains more content so its height is more (in this case 126px) and column B has less content so it remains shorter (here 94px). Now I want to make the height of B = A, considering that height of column A might change dynamically by AJAX but to keep pace with column A, height of column B must also change.
`<div id="A">filer text</div>` | `<div id="B">filler text2</div>`
Now may be by using jQuery or some js we can get the height of element with id #A and set it to #B but the problem lies when the content changes dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#a").css("height", $("#b").css("height") );
```

Which then could be put in the callback function of, say:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success:function(msg){
    // could be optimized by storing off of the comparision
    if( $("#a").height() > $("#b").height() ){
      $("#b").css("height", $("#a").css("height") );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: and this should be enclosed in `$(document).ready` or something else?

Comment: You can if you'd like, but as my edit says, if you're loading the content off of an AJAX request, it'd be easier to just run it from there. Or you can make it into its own function and call it both from .ready() and success:

Comment: He's simply saying attach to the event that caused the resize to begin with.. in this case an ajax event.

Comment: I would use `$('#a').height($('#b').height())`. Same thing, but shorter :) I wonder if it is slower...

Comment: @George: I think the only difference is that .height() is unitless, making it better suited for calculations.

Comment: If `#a` is always bigger than `#b` this won't be a problem. Just keep in mind that if `#b` ever is bigger then `#a`, then this particular solution won't work.

Comment: @scurker: Good call, I added a quick check to my sample.

Comment: If I am not wrong the code should be `$("#b").css("height", $("#a").css("height") );`

Comment: @tunetosuraj: Good call, fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Without JQuery:

```
var d = document;
d.getElementById("B").style.height = d.getElementById("A").offsetHeight;
```